# Regex; How to match all that is not a trailing number?

Tags: regex

I'm not sure if I may ask questions like this here, but I'll try.

I have multiple files. The file name has the following pattern:

`Lorem_Ipsum1054.html`

The `Lorem_Ipsum` isn't fixed in length. Using [Better Rename 10](https://itunes.apple.com/app/better-rename-10/id1063663640?mt=12) I want to change the file name as follows: `1054.html`.

Means: I need to match everything except of the trailing number. This number may vary in length.

Means: I need to match ever everything that is not a trailing number to replace it with [Better Rename 10](https://itunes.apple.com/app/better-rename-10/id1063663640?mt=12) with nothing.

Who can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match anything until the last digit sequence use

```
.*\D(?=\d)
```

The `.*` would slurp anything (including digits, spaces, etc.) until a non-digit followed by a digit (`\D(?=\d)`). And since the `.*` is greedy, it will take up anything until *the last* non-digit before a digit.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/uOoqXX/1

Comment: Hi @DmitryEgorov, thanks, this woks. I've another similar question. Should I make a new post or can I ask you here?

Comment: Hi @David! It depends on how much new value the community may gain from that new question. If you feel it's really similar, try ask here.

Comment: Okay, I have the following: `some text162</title>some text`. I need to remove the number (in this case `162`) before `</title>`. Means: I need to change `some text162</title>some text` to `some text</title>some text`. Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Try with `^(\w*?)(?=\d+\.html)` and replace with `""` empty string.</strike>

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ellO46/1/)

---

Since extension is excluded by default and numbers and spaces are present in file name go with following regex.

**Regex:** `^([\w ]*?)(?=\d+$)`

**Explanation:**

`^([\w ]*?)` will look for characters, spaces as few as it can before trailing digits which is found by `(?=\d+$)` but not matched.

Replace with empty string `''`.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ellO46/3/)**

Comment: Don't want wo work. Is there a way to match everything except the last four trailing characters?

Comment: Yes this is matching everything except last trailing number as you mentioned in question.

Comment: So you mean there should be only number ? Or `.html` should also be removed ?

Comment: So now that extension is excluded by default you only wish to keep the trailing digits and remove other characters. Right ?

Comment: That's not the solution. It will fail in case there is any number in the string. Yes space can be added. Replace `\w` with `[\w ]`. But this is not it. If you change one specification whole regex needed to be thought over again.

Comment: You're right `^([\w ]*?)(?=\d+\.html)` seems to work now.